# libopencv_core.so.2.4: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, gcc, g++

I have installed OpenCV 3.3.0 to Ubuntu 16.04. Just want to compile this code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp"
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <cmath>

using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    try
    {
        int kernel_size = 3;
        cv::Mat src_host = cv::imread("crack2.jpg");
        cv::Mat gray_img, avg, kernel;
        cv::gpu::GpuMat dst, src;
        src.upload(src_host);

        cv::gpu::threshold(src, dst, 128.0, 255.0, CV_THRESH_BINARY);

        cv::Mat result_host;
        dst.download(result_host);

        std::cout<< "Done!!!" <<std::endl;

    }catch(const cv::Exception& ex)
    {
        std::cout<<"Error: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

g++ -o main gpu_thresh.cpp 'pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs' -lopencv_gpu -lopencv_core

g++ -L/usr/local/lib -o main gpu_thresh.cpp 'pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs' -lopencv_gpu -lopencv_core

I tried to compile it with these ways but still giving same warning and error.

> /usr/bin/ld: warning: libopencv_core.so.2.4, needed by
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_gpu.so,
>   may conflict with libopencv_core.so.3.3 /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccdhLGL0.o:
>   undefined reference to symbol '_ZN2cv3gpu6GpuMat7releaseEv'
>   //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.so.2.4: error adding
>   symbols: DSO missing from command line collect2: error: ld returned 1
>   exit status

What should I do?

Comment: How did you install OpenCV 3.3? It seems like you've two versions of OpenCV on your machine.

Comment: From resource , I stopped first installation in "make -j 4" because I forget the add WITH_CUDA=ON flag, I didn't use c++ and opencv in ubuntu before

Comment: Also if I run this 
pkg-config --modversion opencv
it show me only 1 result

Comment: Go to chat.stackoverflow.com and join group: `OpenCV Related`. I am online there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no `opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp` in OpenCV 3.3. If your code compiles then it means that you've both OpenCV 2.4 and 3.3 on your machine.

In OpenCV 3.3, include:

```
#include <opencv2/core/cuda.hpp>
```

and then use

```
cv::cuda::GpuMat img;
```

See details [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/d1/d1e/group__cuda.html).

**Edit:** I just noticed your compilation method. When using `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs`, you don't need to manually add the libopencv files anymore.

Just do: `g++ -o main gpu_thresh.cpp 'pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs'`

Comment: gpu_thresh.cpp:79:7: error: ‘cv::gpu’ has not been declared
   cv::gpu::GpuMat dst, src;

Comment: undefined reference to `cv::gpu::GpuMat::upload(cv::Mat const&)' and bunch of error like this